# Mongo DB Query to get records which match two field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am adding below records in collection

```
db.mycollection.insertMany([
{student : 1 , course : 1},
{student : 1 , course : 2},
{student : 2 , course : 1},
{student : 2 , course : 2},
{student : 3 , course : 1}
])
```

I want to get all students who applied for course 1 and 2. what should be query for same in mongo db ?

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$student", // group by student
        "courses": { $push: "$course" } // remember all courses in an array
    }
}, {
    $match: { // filter
        "courses": { // where "courses"
            $all: [ 1, 2 ] // contains both 1 and 2
        }
    }
}])
```